# AppleScript to Shell-Script

Tags: shell, applescript, paragraph

When I copy multiple paragraphs of data like

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

to my clipboard on Mac I can access its elements via AppleScript through

```
on run {input, parameters}
set theClip to input as text
set value of variable "Empfänger" of front workflow to paragraph 1 of theClip
set value of variable "Betreff" of front workflow to paragraph 2 of theClip
set value of variable "Textkörper" of front workflow to paragraph 3 of theClip
end run
```

and write it to Automator variables. Can I do the same thing in Shell-Script? When I run

```
for f in "$@"
do
echo "$f"
done
```

it seems like everything is stored in $1. 
Actually, I wouldn't mind to use paragraphs as separator but a configurable sign like {NEXT} or something similar.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where/how are you running the shell script? It doesn't seem to be looking at the Clipboard contents at all.

Comment: It's in Automator and Clipboard is handed over "as arguments"

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the contents of the Mac's Clipboard inside a shell script?

Comment: No, I already have the content in the shell either via the code above or via pbpaste.

Comment: What I need is a way to break down the Clipboard content into paragraphs as with the Apple Script Code

Comment: I don't see how you differentiate a *"paragraph"* from a *"line"*. Your example is not ideal as they are the same. What do you actually have? And how do you want them to be separated out please?

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to be happy to treat a line as a paragraph. So, I'll do the same. So, if you copy your three lines of sample data into your clipboard by selecting them below and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and you want to separate them into shell variables, as you say:

```
para1=$(pbpaste | sed -ne '1p')
```

and check:

```
echo "$para1"
line 1
```

Likewise:

```
para2=$(pbpaste | sed -ne '2p')
para3=$(pbpaste | sed -ne '3p')
```

---

Or, if you mean you want the lines in an array:

```
paras=( $(pbpaste) )
echo ${paras[0]}
line1

echo ${paras[1]}
line2
```

Or, if you want loop over the elements:

```
for p in "${paras[@]}" ; do echo $p; done
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great already! To be honest I thought lines is the only way to separate the paragraphs.
What I actually like to achieve is handing over spreadsheet fields to Thunderbird via
 
{./thunderbird -compose "to=$para1,subject=$para2,body=$para3"}

But now I realize that this runs into trouble since the body has a lot of special signs including paragraphs. Is there a way to resolve this if I merge all the data into one spreadsheet cell separating parameters with e.g. -----

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Sometimes I think you are trying to write Applescript, sometimes I think you're trying to write a `bash` script, sometimes I think you are trying to write an Email... maybe using Excel, and there's a clipboard involved.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion! In fact, all of the above is right: I have a spreadsheet (online, not Excel) with customer data, e.g. email, status and so forth. With this data I would like to automatically generate emails. The data changes regularly, so an export is not an option. I thought of the clipboard as a fast way to dynamically extract data and of Automator as a way to process it via a key shortcut (Cmd+C --> clipboard; Cmd+*whatever* --> run automator and open Thunderbird). I started with AppleScript but it runs into error 212 when I use it with a shortcut. Therefore, I try bash now.